# Mobile double tap issue

Tags: html, css, django

I was developing a website using django. Everything is responsive the way I wanted it to be, but when I change to mobile mode, the dropdown menus needed double tap to send me to the link I wanted. single tap is acting as a hover evenif I don't have hover effect. Here is my code.

html code:

```
<div class="dropdown-toggle" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true">
                <strong class="text-uppercase">{{ user.username }} <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></strong>
              </div>
<ul class="custom-menu">
              <li><a href="{% url 'account' %}">{% "Account" %}</a></li>
              <li><a href="{% url 'orders' %}"></i> {% "Orders " %}</a></li>
              <li><a href="{% url 'logout' %}"> {% "Logout" %}</a></li>
            </ul>
```

css code:

```
.custom-menu {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 15px;
  background: #FFF;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.175);
  box-shadow: 0px 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.175);
  z-index: 100;
  top: 100%;
  min-width: 200px;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s all;
  transition: 0.3s all;
}
.dropdown.open>.custom-menu {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

It works on desktop but it needs double tap on mobile. I have tried using @media (pointer: fine) {}, but it makes the dropdown always visible.

Thankyou in advance for your help!

Comment: Anywhere we can see the working code? This isn't enough.

Comment: @andy-hoffman I edited the question, but the important codes are these. When ever I make the visibility: visible, it works on mobile too, but I wanted a dropdown on mobile like the desktop.